# 'atom' command not working even though installer package has been set as an environment variable

Tags: command-prompt

I am relatively new to the command prompt. I am working on a windows computer, and I installed atom on it. I want to be able to open atom from the command prompt, but I am getting an error that

```
"'atom' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".
```

using the 'atom filename' syntax for the command.

To make the shortcut for 'atom', I copied the path of the installer package, and set it as an environment variable in 'User variables for henry', under 'Path'. I looked on several forums and it seems like I am doing everything needed.

here is the directory of the installer package and .exe file:

```
C:\Users\henry\AppData\Local\atom\atom.exe
```

and in the command prompt I use the following syntax:

```
atom filename
```

Yet this does not seem to be working. Is there anything incorrect in the way I have gone about this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is what i did to fix the problem

1. open file explorer and then on the view tab, click show hidden items
2. open cmd (Win + R)
3. type SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe and then click enter
4. this will open system properties, advanced tab. Click on Environment Variables
5. on user variables for (username) click new
6. under variable name type Path, then click Browser Directory and navigate to C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\atom\bin then click ok all through till you exit system properties
7. relaunch cmd
8. navigate to the directory of your project eg C:\exercise\project and hit enter
9. type atom . and hit enter

Answer (score 1):

That's because by default atom is not added to the system path in windows installation, hence cmd is unable to recognize it. To use atom from cmd/terminal you need to add atom to the path.
This can be done by editing the Environment variable in the control panel.

1. search for an `environment variable` in windows start section >> in user variable select the path tab then click the edit option >> then click the new option >> paste the path to your atom installation in windows here >> then click okay every windows and close.

for the new atom version, the path for installation is.

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.57.0
```

the last directory is of the version of the atom installed in your system.
Then: don't forget to restart your terminal. any changes are reflected in the terminal only after restarting.

The process is the same for sublime text and vs code also. Pretty much every application you installed if not configuring path by default You have to do it manually following the same prodcedure.